# How to reference/use a Pascal unit in another unit, privately?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I am a beginner in Pascal. I am trying to create a Simple "Prediction" game in Pascal. For that, I am using multiple units to kind of abstract away the details. One units is board.pas, in which I have declared a type matrix, which is just a 2x2 array.

```
matrix = array of array of Integer;
```

I want to use this type in another unit (players.pas), but I want this to be implemented privately (under implementation) and not be publicly available under interface. But if I put

```
uses board.pas;
```

under implementation, the compiler throws the error "Identifier matrix not found" as there is a procedure "prototype" before it under interface where I am using it. Here is the code:

```
interface

type
    pType = (Human, Computer);
    Player = record
        player_name : record
            firstname, lastname : String;               
        end;
        score : Integer;
        case player_type : pType of
            Human : ();
            Computer : (level, current_prediction : Integer)
        end;


procedure getDetails(num : Integer; var p : Player);
procedure evaluate_prediction(var p : Player; real_board, game_board : matrix);


implementation  
  uses board;
```

I hope I have made my question clear. I can put "uses board.pas;" just after "interface" but I wanted to know out of curiosity that is there any way possible to keep it "hidden" under implementation...? I hope the question is clear.

Comment: No. If you want to use the type in the `interface` section, it has to be declared in the `interface` section's uses clause. You can't use a type before it has been declared.

Comment: Ken already answered your question. But if matrix is a simple 2x2 array, why on earth did you make it a dynamic array of dynamic arrays of Integer? Why not just an `array[0..1, 0..1] of Integer`? No need to allocate, no need to check bounds (known at compile time), simple handling, no reference count with lock, etc.

Comment: The extension is of the file, the USES line expects a module identifier. Don't use an extension

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, thank you for your answer. I declared it as a separate type for two reasons:
1- By making the code more simple, and readable, kind of. Instead of typing array[1..n, 1..2] in every function/procedure that uses it, and there are a lot, I just wanted to simplify it.
2- As for the dynamic part, I don't know the initial size of the board. It will be decided by the users according to how much of their time they want to waste. I may revert it back to array[1..MAX_SIZE, 1..2] later. Declaring it as a type allowed me to propagate a change in one unit to all units who depend on it.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort Oh thanks. I just typed the extension here by mistake. I didn't make such a stupid mistake in the program, although I did use "=" instead of ":=" multiple times out of habit, and then tore some hair (my own) while debugging.

Comment: @Muhammad: I didn't say you should re-declare the type over and over again. Only once. But why as a doubly dynamic `array of array of Integer` instead of a simple *static* array type? The latter is simpler. If the size must be dynamic, make it an `array of array[0..1] of Integer`, or declare the last part, `array[0..1] of Integer` separately. `array of array of` declarations are usually awkward to use and don't easily allow you to access the second dimension elements as a whole.

Comment: @Muhammad: I'd rather do: `element = array[0..1] of Integer; matrix = array of element;` or some such. That way, you can declare and access individual `element` types, which makes things easier to handle.

Comment: As Ken said, this can't be done. If the functions that have matrix parameters are declared in the interface section, the unit must be "used" in the interface section too. There is no way around that. You *could* declare matrix as an untyped pointer and fill the actual type in in the implementation section, but you would have to cast `Pointer` to `PMatrix` every time, and you would have to use pointers anyway. Not sure if I would do that. Or you could make the parameters untyped const parameters: `const real_board, game_board);` but that would also require casts, similar to untyped pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Rudy Velthuis answered your question. For your simple prototype, use a 2x2 static array. However, I will assume you have a good reason to have made `matrix` (here `TMatrix`) a new type, and have records instead classes.

### How to hide your TMatrix type?

- Option 1. Truly hidden. Declare your `TMatrix` type in the implementation section of a unit. This way you will be treating this type as an implementation detail. It will not be shared. Changes in this implementation detail will not propagate to other units:

  ```
  interface

  procedure evaluate_prediction(var p : TPlayer);

  implementation

  type
    TMatrix = array of array of integer;

  var
    real_board, game_board :TMatrix;
  ```
- Option 2. Implementation use. Declare your `TMatrix` type in the interface section of some unit, lets say (as you did) `board.pas`. Now everything that uses this type and is self-contained should be declared in this very unit. Other units should use this type only in their implementation section and all not self-contained methods should be declared in their implementation section too.

  ```
  unit board

  interface

  type
    TMatrix = array of array of integer;

  var
    real_board, game_board :TMatrix;

  implementation
  ```

Comment: Thanks. I was declaring my own type "matrix" just to make the code more simple, so that I can use it in the many functions/procedure that use it without typing array[1..m, 1..n] again and again.
 My question was more towards how can I not let other units know which units a specific unit is using ...?
Like, can I, in some way, hide which units a program/unit "uses" ...?
Stupid question, but I had to get it out of my mind.

Comment: The real question was how to declare functions that take a `matrix` in the `interface` section without making the structure of a `matrix` known. That can't be done by "using" the unit that declares it in the `implementation` section.

Comment: I dont think so, Rudy. He explicitly asked "any way possible to keep it hidden".

Comment: @Geek I am afraid your code will become more and more complicated if you create types just because you don't want to type.